# working bar charts/tables with sproutcore

Tags: jfreechart, google-visualization, sproutcore, bar-chart

I am currently working on a task which want to display bar charts/tables on the website.

The application is using: sproutcore (1.6) as front-end, Java Restful as backend.

However, I can't find some useful library for charts in sproutcore. Are there any ideas for that?

I search on the website, I feel the google chart tools is quite good, also jFreechart as backend is also a good choice.

I am not sure how to integrate that to sproutcore.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using Flot to display charts on my Sproutcore app.

To use it, you need to create a flot directory inside the frameworks folder which will include the jquery.flot.js file (I've also include jquery.flot.pie.js file) and a core.js file with this content:

```
sc_require('jquery.flot.js');
sc_require('jquery.flot.pie.js');

Flot = SC.Object.create({
  plot: $.plot
}) ;
```

Then, you need to add this new library to your buildfile :

```
config :yourapp,  
  :required => ['flot']
```

To display your charts in your app, you can use this custom view that I made to work with Flot:

```
GX.FlotView = SC.View.extend({
  classNames: ['flot'],

  //ex: [{ data: [[1326366000000, 1500], [1326452400000, 600]], label: 'title of the serie' }, ...]
  data: [],

  /* 
  ex: {
    legend: { show: true },
    series: line, points,
    xaxis: { mode: "time", timeformat: "%d/%m/%y", }
    grid: { backgroundColor: { colors: ["#FFF", "#fefefe"]}},
  } 
  */
  options: [],


  render: function(context, firstTime) { 
    var frame = this.get('frame'),
        data = this.get('data'), 
        options = this.get('options');

    // To avoid an error with flot, we check if width and height > 0
    if(frame.width > 0 && frame.height > 0 && data && data.length) {  
      var layer = this.get('layer'),
          plot = Flot.plot(layer, data, options);
    }
  },


  viewDidResize: function() {
    this.invokeLast(function() {
      if (this.get('isVisibleInWindow')) this.set('layerNeedsUpdate', YES);
    });
  }.observes('data', 'data.[]'),

});
```

Then, you just have to bind the data and the option properties with your data.